# What does if mean here: "He's a good driver, if a little over-confident"

Tags: word-usage

What does "if" mean here:

> He's a good driver, **if** a little over-confident

when can I also use it like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "if" here means "even though".

You might expect that a good driver should not be over confident. The speaker here acknowledges that expectation, and says it's true in spite of the occasional over-confidence.

You can use "if" this way under similar circumstances.

Comment: like may and but for example:

Comment: he may be a good driver but a little over-confident.

Comment: @coolguy Yes, those would do.

Comment: Also ***albeit*** - which I think is closer to ***if*** in OP's context than ***even though***.